# custom bounds constraint in basinhopping optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to maximize a sum of two monotonically increasing functions `f(x) = f1(x) + f2(x)` within the given bounds, say `x = 0 to 6`. The curves of the two functions are: [image]

To solve this I'm using basinhopping function from `scipy` package.

I would like to specify a constraint for using the bounds. Specifically, I want the summation of bounds to be lesser than or equal to a constant value. i.e. In my implementation below, I want `x[0] + x[1] <= C` where `C = 6`.

In the above figure, for `C = 6`, approximately `x[0] = 2 and x[1] = 4` (4 + 2 =<=6) will yield the maximum value. My question is how to specify this constraint? If it's not possible, is there another optimization function that is better suited for this problem?

```
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
from math import tanh


def f(x):
    return -(f1(x[0]) + f2(x[1]))  # -ve sign for maximization


def f1(x):
    return tanh(x)


def f2(x):
    return (10 ** (0.2 * x))

# Starting point
x0 = [1., 1.]

# Bounds
xmin = [1., 1.]
xmax = [6., 6.]


# rewrite the bounds in the way required by L-BFGS-B
bounds = [(low, high) for low, high in zip(xmin, xmax)]

minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="L-BFGS-B", bounds=bounds)

result = basinhopping(f,
                      x0,
                      minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
                      niter=200)

print("global max: x = [%.4f, %.4f], f(x0) = %.4f" % (result.x[0], result.x[1], result.fun))
```

Comment: If they're both monotonically increasing, won't the maximum just be the value at the maximum x?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with COBYLA constrained optimization, though I don't know how to do it with L-BFGS-B.  You can add constraints like the following:

```
def constraint1(x):
  return 6 - x[0]

def constraint2(x):
  return 6 - x[0] - x[1]

def constraint3(x):
  return x[0] - 1
```

To add these constraints to the minimizer, use:

```
c1={"type":"ineq","fun":constraint1}
c2={"type":"ineq","fun":constraint2}
c3={"type":"ineq","fun":constraint3}
minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="COBYLA",constraints=(c1,c2,c3))
```

When I run this example, I get the result `global max: x = [1.0000, 5.0000], f(x0) = -10.7616`

Note, I haven't tested whether you need to add a constraint4 that `x[1]>1`.

For more reading, see the documentation for cobyla:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html

Comment: basinhopping ignores constraints when taking steps, though https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7799